# PHP Error loading, editing, then saving XML DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, xml

I am getting the following output when running a simple script which loads a `XML` file, adds a node with a few child nodes to the document, then saves the `XML` file. Here is the link to this XML file being referenced:  http://msgrapp.com/test/ajaxchat/messages.xml

> Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Extra content at the end of the document
>   in /home1/dstamp/public_html/messages.xml, line: 3 in
>   /home1/dstamp/public_html//sendMessage.php on line 4

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $doc->load('messages.xml');

    $root = $doc->createElement('MESSAGE');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

    $dateNode = $doc->createElement('DATE');
    $dateNode = $root->appendChild($dateNode);
    $dateText = $doc->createTextNode(date("F j Y g:i a"));
    $dateText = $dateNode->appendChild($dateText);

    $senderNode = $doc->createElement('SENDER');
    $senderNode = $root->appendChild($senderNode);
    $senderText = $doc->createTextNode($_GET['sender']);
    $senderText = $senderNode->appendChild($senderText);

    $messageNode = $doc->createElement('TEXT');
    $messageNode = $root->appendChild($messageNode);
    $messageText = $doc->createTextNode($_GET['message']);
    $messageText = $messageNode->appendChild($messageText);

    $doc->save('messages.xml');
    echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Please show us *exactly* what your XML file looks like. If the file is large then the last 10 lines would probably be enough. Edit your question and put the XML there; do not put it in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra content error is caused by having two of the same node, in this case the MESSAGE node, as a root element.

You could add a new root element MESSAGES for example, and then add more MESSAGE elements within that

This will Help you : [Alternately getting the error (Extra content at the end of the document )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785933/alternately-getting-the-error-extra-content-at-the-end-of-the-document)

Comment: Hey thanks...one question though, when I load messages.xml into the $doc variable, what's the best way to access the root node?  Is there an array of nodes that are accessible for DOMDocument objects?  Or would I use $doc->getElementsByTagname("MESSAGES").  I need to be able to access the root node MESSAGES to append MESSAGE nodes to it.

Also I noticed the answer in the link you posted is using the SimpleXML extension, I would like to achieve this without using it.

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer.  Can access the root node to append children using $doc->documentElement.